# Include jscolor in ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a index.php page and I am inluding other pages in index.php like this:

```
function urlpage(url){
    $('#page').load(url);
}
```

jscolor javascript working in index.php but when I load a page (test.php) jscolor not working in this loaded page. What can I do?

I added also this in test.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscolor.js"></script>
```

EDİT : I solved the problem like this :

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jscolor.init();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: With the same way( jscolor.init() ) I have also resolved my problem(). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to reinitialize jscolor once your load function is done.

```
$('#page').load(url, function () {
    var myPicker = new jscolor.color($('#myField'), {})
});
```

[Also check other examples.](http://jscolor.com/try.php#manual-binding)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I resolved the problem with another way

Comment: @webmaster please share how you solved it and what was the issue.

Comment: I edited my question and I did write there how I solved.

Answer (score 5):

jscolor.init() did not work for me, and So I called

jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jscolor.installByClassName("jscolor");
});
```

Hope it helps